# Preventing notification sounds from interfering with sound app

Tags: ios, notifications, sound-synthesis

I'm making a synth kind of app for the iPad. Problem is - whenever I'm playing and someone messages me, the sound lowers the synth app's sound. It is kind of disruptive. 
How do I prevent this? Maybe you can see the notifications but the sounds doesn't automatically lower the volume in the synth. 
I can't imagine performing with my app and getting it interrupted by all the iMessages!

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Just looking for a way to stop the notifications from disrupting my app sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to control that stuff.  It's part of iOS and no app is allowed to interfere with it.  Perhaps in a later version of iOS, they allow an app to grab exclusive access to the sound output, and it'll bring up a warning like "SynthApp would like full control of sound.  Allow or Disallow?"  But for now, there's nothing like that...

I'd recommend telling people in the documentation to turn off those sounds in the Settings app if they're using it in a live setting or whatever.  Also, if your app supports recording the sounds that it generates, the other sounds shouldn't interfere with that, as your recording algorithm wouldn't have access to the final mixed product anyway, it would only see the sounds that your app specifically is generating.

Comment: Also, most notifications happen because of access to the internet, so just tell your users to put their device in airplane mode, that should handle most everything.  Then they don't need to go through a bunch of individual settings.